# Scraping data from table with unique ID rows

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape from [this](https://us.soccerway.com/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/matches/) website. My objective is to collect the most recent 10 results (win/loss/draw) of ANY team, I am just using this specific team as an example. The source for an individual row is:

```
<tr class="odd      match no-date-repetition" data-timestamp="1515864600" id="page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-2463021" data-competition="8">
        <td class="day no-repetition">Sat</td>


        <td class="full-date" nowrap="nowrap">13/01/18</td>
        <td class="competition"><a href="/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/" title="Premier League">PRL</a></td>

          <td class="team team-a ">
              <a href="/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/" title="Tottenham Hotspur">
                Tottenham Hotspur
              </a>
          </td>

        <td class="score-time score">
          <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/" class="result-win">

            4 - 0

          </a>
        </td>
          <td class="team team-b ">
            <a href="/teams/england/everton-football-club/674/" title="Everton">
              Everton
            </a>
          </td>
        <td class="events-button button first-occur">
            <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/#events" title="View events" class="events-button-button ">View events</a>
        </td>

          <td class="info-button button">

              <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/" title="More info">More info</a>



          </td>




      </tr>
```

You can see in the `<td class="score-time score"`, the result is stored.
My knowledge of Python and web crawling is pretty limited, so my current code is:

```
res2 = requests.get(soccerwayURL)
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
elems2 = soup2.select('#page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-2463021 > td.score-time.score')
print(elems2[0].text.strip())
```

This prints out '4-0'. That is good, but the issue arises when I try to access a different row. The 7-digit number (2463021 in the example above) is unique to that row. That means that if I want to get the score from a different row, I would have to find that unique 7-digit number and place it in the CSS selector `'#page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-******* > td.score-time.score'` where the asterisks are the unique number.

The online course I took only showed how to reference things by the CSS Selector, so I am  unsure how I can go about retrieving the scores without manually taking the CSS Selector for each row.

Within the `<td class="score-time score">` class, there is another class that reads `class="result-win">`. Ideally I would like to be able to pull just that `"result-win"` because I am not looking for the score of the game, I am only looking for the outcome of win, loss, or draw.

I hope this is a little clearer. I greatly appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: Please include the actual source, using the code formatting tool, rather than a picture of it. It would also be very helpful if you could include the Python code which is failing.

Comment: You should also let us know *why* you need the ID. Are you using it to filter the rows? (If you want it to work for all teams, just download all the rows, and ignore the ID field.) If it were me, I would scrape all of the data, convert it to a CSV (or list of dicts), and filter the *data* rows rather than directly the HTML rows.

Comment: @jpaugh Hey, sorry for not having much information in the post, first-time poster. This is the actual source: view-source:https://us.soccerway.com/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/matches/ I'm not sure if that's what you meant exactly, I'm brand new to HTML/Python. My goal is to collect the result (win, loss, draw) of the last ten games played by any team. In the element of the the actual score, there is a "class = "result-win"" which I would ideally like to grab.

Comment: @jpaugh Here is the code that I have so far:
https://imgur.com/a/MeLw3 The soup2.select parameter is the CSS selector of the actual score element. The problem is that the match idea is in that selector, so if I were to use that same code for a different team, it would not work. I apologize if any of my terminology is incorrect or unclear, I'm still learning all of this as I go :)

Comment: Please copy and paste the source into your post. You can use the code button in the editor to format it properly. If some one wants to try something out, they have to re-type everything from the picture.

Comment: @jpaugh Sorry, this is my first time posting here so I'm running into some issues with this. I'm trying to use the code button but it is exceeding the character limit. I have the entire page's source here (https://pastebin.com/uHRBZdAF), and the source of the table is here (https://pastebin.com/1S5fpbHB). I think I'm going about this very directly, using the HTML code as how I access the table data. In the source for one row, "#page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-2462800 > td.score-time.score" is the selector for the score of the game. Within that there is "class="result-win""

Comment: @jpaugh Ideally, I would like to be able to pull that class="result-win" as I only care about the result of the game, not the score itself. I appreciate you working with me on this as I'm at a roadblock right now with how to go about parsing this table. Thanks.

Comment: Normally, you want to copy in only the part of the code that is relevant. Perhaps a few `tr`s, plus the few lines of Python which aren't working. TBH, I'm still having trouble understanding your problem. Check out [mcve] for details on how to create a clear problem statement.

Comment: @jpaugh I rewrote my initial post, hopefully that is more clear on what I am looking for. Overall, my objective statement is, "collect the results of the last 10 games played by any team."